# Test page title with NightwatchJS

Tags: nightwatch.js

I need to check if the title of a page contains "Homepage".

I try the following
`browser.expect.element('title').text.to.contain('Homepage');` but the element `title` always comes back empty.

Any other element works but `title` seems to behave differently. How can I check for a substring?

**Example**:

Works:

```
browser
  .url('https://stackoverflow.com')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000)
  .assert.title('Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers');
```

Doesn't work:

```
browser
  .url('https://stackoverflow.com')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000)
  .expect.element('title').text.to.contain('Developers');
```

Output: `Expected element <title> text to contain: "Developers"  - expected "contain 'Developers'" but got: ""`

Yet this works: `browser.expect.element('h1').text.to.contain('Learn, Share, Build');`

It seems only visible elements can be tested, so I'm not sure how I can check something hidden.

Comment: post the HTML of the webpage

Comment: Are you waiting till page load? Probably it is trying to get title before the page is loaded

Comment: Examples added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium [only interacts with visible elements](http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/").

This works:

```
   browser.getTitle(function(title) {
     this.assert.ok(title.includes("Homepage"));
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems title methods were added to nightwatch

Using assert, you can check for the whole title 
https://nightwatchjs.org/api/#assert-title
`browser.assert.title("Nightwatch.js");`

Using expect, you can check for a part of it
https://nightwatchjs.org/api/expect/#expect-title-
`browser.expect.title().to.contain('value');` `startWith` and `endWith` are also available that way, even regexp check `browser.expect.title().to.match(/value/);`

Answer (score 0):

We have created generic command which can be used thought the application 
 before() will wait for the timeout set before failing the assert

```
exports.command = function waitForTitleContains(pageTitle) {
   this.expect
    .title().to.contain(pageTitle)
    .before(); //defaults to waitForConditionTimeout from nightwatch.conf
};
```